# require (browserify) not working correctly when assigned (empty object), but works when inline

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, reactjs, browserify

I have the following component definitions in React (coffee jsx):

```
CompUtils = require './../utils/comp-utils'

...

  render: ->
    console.log CompUtils # prints {} (empty object)
    <div>
      Then
      {CompUtils.getConstructComponent @props.construct, @props.onUpdate, @props.onRemove}
    </div>
```

But this works:

```
  render: ->
    console.log require('./../utils/comp-utils')
    <div>
      Then
      {require('./../utils/comp-utils').getConstructComponent @props.construct, @props.onUpdate, @props.onRemove}
    </div>
```

I am absolutely confounded by this. Note that `CompUtils` have been used successfully in other components.

Comment: Like you said it should work as it's working in other components so it must be something specific to this one.

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript code being generated by coffeescript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually when you get an empty object from a require call, it's because you have circular dependencies. So you require **A**, which requires **B**, which requires **C**, which requires **A**. In that case **C** will get an empty object representing **A**, because **A** hasn't finished exporting its functions/objects yet and **A** will only be fully available to **C** on the next tick, when **A** has finished exporting.

Here's an example:

```
// a.js
var b = require('./b');
module.exports = {
  doStuff: function () {

  }
}

// b.js
var c = require('./c');

// c.js
var a = require('./a');

// This will fail because a.js hasn't exported doStuff yet, since a required b, which 
// required c, which required a.
a.doStuff();
```

The reason you get an empty object is because Browserify creates an empty object representing `module.exports` for that module before the module code runs. Which means that another module can require it before it's finished, it's just not fully baked.

Comment: Found the circular dependency. Great help!!